# Angular @ViewChild magic

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a nested menu which is rendered recursively. I need to have active classes on parent's elements so that they are stressed. I'm trying to achieve it via assigning `routerLinkActive` to id and then checking it from component via `@ViewChild`.

```
<ng-container routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <li [class.active]="rla.isActive || isActive">
    <a [routerLink]="menuItem.link" *ngIf="menuItem.link; else noLink">
      <i *ngIf="menuItem.faClass" class="fa fa-{{menuItem.faClass}}"></i>
      {{menuItem.name}} <span *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
    <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0">
      <ul class="nav child_menu" [class.active]="isActive || rla.isActive"
          *ngFor="let item of menuItem.children">
        <app-menu-item [menuItem]="item" (checkActive)="updateActiveState()"></app-menu-item>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
  </li>

  <!--In case there is no link provided (has children)-->
  <ng-template #noLink>
    <li [class.active]="isActive">
      <a (click)="toggleActive()">
        <i *ngIf="menuItem.faClass" class="fa fa-{{menuItem.faClass}}"></i>
        {{menuItem.name}} <span *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

And here is my component

```
public menuSize;
  public isActive = false;

  @Input() menuItem: MenuItem;
  // @Input() routerActive: boolean;

  @ViewChild('rla') routerActive;

  @Output() checkActive: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @ViewChild(MenuItemComponent) menuComponent: MenuItemComponent;

  private hostActive = true;
  private hostActiveSm = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private uss: UiStateService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uss.menuSubject.subscribe(msg => {
      this.menuSize = msg;
      if (this.menuSize === MenuSizes.sm) {
        this.hostActive = false;
        this.hostActiveSm = true;
      } else {
        this.hostActive = true;
        this.hostActiveSm = false;
      }
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe((e: Event) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.updateActiveState();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateActiveState();
    console.log('This is active', this.routerActive);

    if (this.routerActive.isActive) {
      console.log('emitting');
      this.checkActive.emit();
    }
  }

  public toggleActive(): void {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    // if (this.menuComponent) {
    //   this.menuComponent.isActive = true;
    // }
  }

  private updateActiveState(): void {
    // reset previous state
    this.isActive = false;
    if (this.menuComponent) {
      this.menuComponent.isActive = false;
    }

    if (this.menuComponent && this.menuComponent.isActive) {
      // console.log('Menu component');
      // console.log(this.menuComponent, this.menuComponent.menuItem.link);
      this.isActive = true;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I console log `this.routerActive` the browser prints out the routerLinkActive objects with property `isActive = true` on activated route.

[image]

However, if I try to console log `this.routerActive.isActive` it prints all 6 falses (as if there were no active route).
[image]

## Update

Just to make it more clear here is more detailed log
[image]

And here is what I've got
[image]

## Update #2

Just tried to make an Object assign and got 6 objects with isActive = false

Answer (score 0):

If you have several similar components you should use @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild, like this

```
@ViewChildren('rla')
routerActives: QueryList<RouterLinkActive>;
```

and then iterate through them to find the one/achieve desired results

```
this.routerActives.forEach((item) => {
...
});
```

Comment: From my scope there is none. Since I render them only if they are present. Moreover, the questions is why when I check object there is `true` but when I print not object but this property then it prints false

Comment: Moreover, as far as I remember, VewChildren is static and when parent element is rendered, but yet child isn't there would be 0 children

Comment: The same result. Still when I print object `isActive` is equal to true. When I print a property it becomes false

Comment: When you log a property you get its current value (in the moment when it was logged).
When you log object you can get the object, and its properties may be fetched later.
So I think something changes the value of `isActive` after you log it.

Comment: But, don't I log the current object's state? It's logging not an assigning an observable value that can change over time. It's logging. It works like a snapshot

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Xcalibur/en1dt0c7/
Try this one and inspect the logs (expand the object in console).

Comment: How is this possible? When we do console log it should make a kinda snapshot. How the value in console is changed?

Comment: The main thing, is that it indicates that object is changed after you log it.
So, try to find where it is changed (if it may be important). p.s. Chrome developer tools always works like this

Comment: try to change a const to let and see it :)